# How do i work with .osm files in terms of creation of nodes and edges so i can put it on a Djikstra Algorithm?

Tags: android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have a MetroManila.osm file and i parse it so it can read roads only using this command: `--keep = --keep-nodes=highway --keep-ways=`. Is this the right command for filtering only the roads? 
 What i want after parsing is to create a node where there's intersections or curves, or is it possible with just using the whole nodes in MetroManila.osm? Can i create an edge using it and how do i do it? Currently, i'm really lost on what to do since i'm fairly new on android studio and in osmdroid.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't really anything to do with Android or osmdroid.

For learning how to create a routing graph from an OSM file see the related answer at [help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/19213/how-can-i-convert-an-osm-xml-file-into-a-graph-representation). Quoting from it:

1. parse all ways; throw away those that are not roads, and for the others, remember the node IDs they consist of, by incrementing a "link counter" for each node referenced.
2. parse all ways a second time; a way will normally become one edge, but if any nodes apart from the first and the last have a link counter greater than one, then split the way into two edges at that point. Nodes with a link counter of one and which are neither first nor last can be thrown away unless you need to compute the length of the edge.
3. (if you need geometry for your graph nodes) parse the nodes section of the XML now, recording coordinates for all nodes that you have retained.

Also take a look at [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) in the OSM wiki to get some general hints and existing tools and libraries.

Regarding osmdroid: If you don't rely on offline routing then take a look at osmbonuspack, it supports online routing.

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel then just use one of the existing offline routing tools mentioned in the OSM wiki.